# Display more help when asking a question

Tags: feature-request

I notice that most of questions on SO tagged on most used languages (such as c++, java, ...) are due to a serious lack of knlowledge of the languages themselves. Most of the time, one of the first comment is similar to: "Have you ever read a doc about this?".

On every tag page are listed some very useful links to online docs, but I think that it is too bad that these links do not appear clearly when one is writing his question. The idea is simply to mention clearly the link to the tag page, with a special title such as "Have you searched inside these docs", each link appearing whenever a tag is entered.

It will not solve the problem of people not searching in docs (unfortunately), but I think some people may just want useful links where they can find basic information.

Comment: We show links to questions we determine are similar as they ask. When you say docs, are you referring to the tag wiki entries per tag, or the 'related' questions to the side? We also do tag suggestions, but all of it is based on what they type (and in the case of really bad questions, not much to go on quite often).

Comment: To be more clear, I mean the links "Resources" and "FAQs" in the info page of each tag.